# Como puedo crear una estructura en swift para que pueda decodificar un json

Tags: swift4

A traves de una API Rest recibo un json con la siguiente estructura:

```
{
    "estado": 1,
    "datos": [
        {
            "idContacto": "1",
            "primerNombre": "Juan Jose",
            "primerApellido": "Villasetin",
            "telefono": "8899765444",
            "correo": "jjvillasetin@hotmail.com",
            "idUsuario": "1"
        },
        {
            "idContacto": "3",
            "primerNombre": "Ravello",
            "primerApellido": "Manzanillo",
            "telefono": "9999992344",
            "correo": "raveo@hotmail.com",
            "idUsuario": "1"
        }
    ]
}
```

En swift tengo las siguientes estructuras:

```
struct Contacto : Codable {
    let estado : Int
    let datos : Datos
}

struct Datos : Codable {
    let primerNombre : String
    let telefono : String
}
```

Al intentar decodificar el json con la siguiente instrucción:

```
self.contactos = try JSONDecoder().decode([Contacto].self, from: data!)
```

Se dispara el error:

> The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para decodificar un JSON en swift hay muchas opciones y todas validas, puedes utilizar un objeto externo como por ejemplo SWiftyJSON o el Jsondecoder que utilizas. O lo puedes descodificar a mano, así sabes en quelinea puede fallar y que esta pasando. Si el JSOn es largo y complicado le tendrás que dedicar un rato largo, es una tarea pesada y hay que hacer un descodificador por cada estructura. Como suelo hacerlo yo, pues en el struct me creo el descodificador para esa estructura en concreto. Para el JSON que pasas, imaginemos que son obligatorios los campos de primer nombre, primer apellido y teléfono y los otros puede venir a null o rellenos, pero sin los campos obligatorios no puedo aceptar ese dato como valido

dentro de la definición del struct, me creo el decodificador

```
struct Datos {
   //la definición de tus datos
   .....

   static func decodeData(json: [String: AnyObject]) -> Datos? {
        //me aseguro de los datos que tiene que ser obligatorios en caso contrario devuelvo nil
        guard let nom = json["primerNombre"] as? String,
              let ape = json["primerApellido"] as? String,
              let tlf = json["telefono"] as? String
        else {
              //falta algún dato obligatorio
              return nil
        }
        //ahora los datos que si vienen nulo no pasaría nada
        let idContacto = json["idContacto"] as? Int
        let mail = json["correo"] as? String
        let idUser = json["idUsuario"] as? Int

        //ya tengo los datos, creo el modelo
        let m = Datos(id:idContacto, nombre: nom, apellido: ape, telefono: tlf, mail: mail, user: idUser);
        return m
   }
}
```

Pero según tu JSON, los datos van dentro de un array, así que hay que recorrerse ese array para decodificar cada datos. Necesitaremos otro método mas, dentro del struct

```
static func decodeJSON(json: [String: AnyObject]) -> [Datos] {
   //genero el listado de los datos
   var arr: [Datos] = []
   //me recorro el array de datos
   guard let datos = json["datos"] as? [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]
   else {
       //no viene datos, o el json esta mal, devuelvo el array vacío
       return arr
   }

   //me recorro todos los datos que me vienen
   for d in datos {
      if let dat = Datos.decodeData(json: d) {
           //el datos es valido
           arr.append(dat)
       } else {
          //el dato no es valido, aquí haces lo que necesites
       }
   return arr
}
```

Tratar json en swift es bastante pesado, por eso hay muchas herramientas o te lo trabajas a mano. Esta es una opción, la mía, te podrán responder muchas opciones mas y seguramente también te servirán. Para gustos los colores.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha servido de mucho el ejemplo.